# Pass an Array from PHP to PowerShell

Tags: php, powershell

I am trying to pass an array from PHP to PowerShell using the below code but to no luck

//PHP Code

```
$psPath = "powershell.exe -InputFormat none -ExecutionPolicy ByPass  -NoProfile ";
$psDIR = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\";
$psScript = "ps_scripts.ps1";
$runScript = $psDIR. $psScript;
$runCMD = $psPath." ".$runScript." 2>&1 "; 

$array = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
$serialized_array = json_encode($array);
$ps_function_name = "example_function";
exec($runCMD . $ps_function_name . " \"" . $serialized_array . "\"" . " \"" . $another_parameter . "\"", $output, $retval);
```

//PowerShell Code

```
function example_function
{
    $Encodeddata = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $args[1];

    echo $Encodeddata;
}
```

Error

```
            Array ( [0] => At line:1 char:70 [1] => + ... htdocs\ps_scripts.ps1 migrate_skype_op_to_online_1 {Peter:35,Ben:37,J ... [2] => + ~ [3] => Missing argument in parameter list. [4] => + CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException [5] => + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument [6] => ) 1
```

Comment: The serialize function php offers is a language internal solution. It is not meant to hand over structured data to _other_ languages beside php. Use `JSON` instead for the transport, it has more or less become the defacto standard. php offers the functions `json_decode()` and `json_encode()` for that.

Comment: @arkascha 7 , can you suggest how I can json_decode in PowerShell once I json_encode($array) in PHP

Comment: @Manu you can convert JSON to PowerShell object by using `ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $args[1]`

Comment: @arkascha 7 I have tried json_encode, but am getting an error, have modified the script, pls have a look

Comment: @Guenther Schmitz I have tried json_encode, but am getting an error, have modified the script, pls have a look

Comment: So what happens is you take the full string you try to execute at the end of the php script, copy it into a powershell console and execute it?

Comment: @Manu I would export the JSON from PHP to a file (https://blog-en.openalfa.com/how-to-read-and-write-json-files-in-php) and then import that file via PowerShell (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-convert-json-file-to-powershell-object/)

Answer (score 0):

to run a script with parameters you can run `powershell.exe -File c:\xampp\htdocs\ps_scripts.ps1`

so the PHP script should look like this:

```
<?php
$psPath = "powershell.exe -InputFormat none -ExecutionPolicy ByPass  -NoProfile -File ";
$psDIR = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\";
$psScript = "ps_scripts.ps1";
$runScript = $psDIR. $psScript;
$runCMD = $psPath." ".$runScript; 

$array = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
$serialized_array = json_encode($array);

$execCmd = $runCMD . " '" . $serialized_array . "'";
#results to the following - note that the serialized json array is enclosed by single quotes
#powershell.exe -InputFormat none -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoProfile -File C:\xampp\htdocs\test.ps1 '{"Peter":"35","Ben":"37","Joe":"43"}'

exec($execCmd, $output, $retval);

var_dump($output);
?>
```

the PS1 script content is nothing but the following two lines

```
$Encodeddata = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $args[0];
echo $Encodeddata;
```

the `$args` array starts with 0 so `$args[0]` is the first parameter which results to `'{"Peter":"35","Ben":"37","Joe":"43"}'` in this example

in your example the PowerShell code has a function but this function is never called.